# Data Scraping Twitter Data in R

Tags: r

I am pulling in data from Twitter into R and I am hitting two stumbling blocks.

```
twit=searchTwitter("justin timerlake",n=30,lang = "en") 
twit_text=sapply(twit, function(x) x$getText())
corpus=Corpus(VectorSource(twit_text))
```

1) How do I access the string comments in the corpus?? I tried print(corpus) but its not printing. Instead I get this message.

```
print(corpus)
A corpus with 30 text documents
```

2) I am trying to lowercase all the text in the corpus but I am having little success.

I tried these following commands

```
 tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
Error in match.fun(FUN) : could not find function "content_transformer"

tm_map(corpus,Content(tolower))
Error in UseMethod("Content", x) : 
  no applicable method for 'Content' applied to an object of class "function"

tolower(twit_text)
```

the last one seems to stop on messages with weird characters inside such as "í ½í²™"

Comment: One trick you can usually use in R to get information about a variable is to use `names()`, e.g. type `names(corpus)` and see what you get.

Comment: I am getting back "NULL". I am having a hard time accessing the data in the corpus.

Comment: I spoke too soon above.  It appears that the corpus is an intermediary object which is used in a `TermDocumentMatrix`.  Have a look at this blog: https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-text-mining-on-twitter-prayformh370-malaysia-airlines/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert it to lower:

```
corpus = tm_map(corpus, tolower)
```

You can access the text in the corpus by converting it to Document Term Matrix (DTM):

```
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)
```

**Edit**

Typcical Text Cleaning Functions:

```
corpus = tm_map(corpus, tolower);
corpus = tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation);
corpus = tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers);
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, PlainTextDocument)
```

Comment: thanks but I keep getting an error. There are characters in the text like this "í ½í²™" in corpus that is preventing all the commands from working. Is there a way to remove them so the commands could work?

Comment: Thank you so much! The trick to anyone else using this as a reference later is to use the corpus = tm_map(corpus, tolower); after all the other commands on top. Thanks again!

Comment: When I type: DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)
A document-term matrix (1000 documents, 4638 terms)

Non-/sparse entries: 7848/4630152
Sparsity           : 100%
Maximal term length: 963 
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)

Comment: How do I actually access the messages using the DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)   command??